# Excel VBA: Auto increment cell value after each printing

Tags: excel, vba

I found a VBA code on EctendOffice to increment a number in cell after each printing.
Now I need to increment 4 cell values on same page after each printing.
Example: when I set the number of printings to 50, Cell C27 should have a value 1/50, Cell M27 = 2/50, Cell C58 = 3/50, and cell M58 = 4/50. and the next page should be 5/50, 6/50, 7/50, 8/50 etc.

This is the code that I used to print only one label per page and to increment one cell value:

```
Sub IncrementPrint()
'updateby Extendoffice
    Dim xCount As Variant
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
LInput:
    xCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:", "Kutools for Excel")
    If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If (xCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(xCount)) Or (xCount < 1) Then
        MsgBox "error entered, please enter again", vbInformation, "Kutools for Excel"
        GoTo LInput
    Else
        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For I = 1 To xCount
            ActiveSheet.Range("C27").Value = I & " / " & xCount
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        Next
        ActiveSheet.Range("C27").ClearContents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: By applying your logic, the last printed sheet in cell `M58` would have the string `200/50` `(50*4)`. Is that what you're aiming for? I mean wouldn't you rather have `1/200` to `200/200` for `50` copies? Please clarify.

Comment: Another logic could be `1/1/50, 2/1/50, 3/1/50, 4/1/50, 1/2/50, 2/2/50, ..., 4/50/50` with or without the trailing `/50` or switching the first two.

Comment: I mean wouldn't you rather have 1/200 to 200/200 for 50 copies? Please clarify - Yes, that's what I am aiming for. 50 copies with 4 labels - Labels to go from 1/200 to 200/200

Answer (score 2):

### Print Copies of Single Worksheet With Increment

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PrintWithIncrement()
         
    Const WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "C27,M27,C58,M58"
    Const PROMPT As String = "Please enter the number of copies you want to print:"
    Const TITLE As String = "Print With Increment"
    Const DEFAULT_COPIES As Long = 1
    Const MAX_COPIES As Long = 100
    Const APPLY_TOTAL_LOGIC As Boolean = False
    
    Dim pCount As Variant
    Dim Msg As Long
    Dim IsInputValid As Boolean

    Do Until IsInputValid
        pCount = Application.InputBox(PROMPT, TITLE, DEFAULT_COPIES, , , , , 1)
        If VarType(pCount) = vbBoolean Then
            MsgBox "Dialog canceled.", vbExclamation, TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Int(pCount) = pCount Then
            If pCount > 0 Then IsInputValid = True
        End If
        If IsInputValid Then
            If pCount > MAX_COPIES Then
                Msg = MsgBox("This will print " & pCount & " copies." _
                    & vbLf & vbLf & "Are you sure?", _
                    vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, TITLE)
                If vbNo Then IsInputValid = False
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "lnvalid entry: " & pCount & vbLf & vbLf _
                & "Try again.", vbExclamation, TITLE
        End If
    Loop
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WORKSHEET_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(RANGE_ADDRESS)
    rg.NumberFormat = "@"
    Dim tCount As Long: tCount = pCount
    
    If APPLY_TOTAL_LOGIC Then tCount = tCount * rg.Cells.Count
    
    Dim cell As Range, p As Long, t As Long
    
    For p = 1 To pCount
        For Each cell In rg.Cells
            t = t + 1
            cell.Value = t & "/" & tCount
            Debug.Print cell.Value ' Test with this first! Uncomment later!
            'ws.PrintOut ' Out-comment when done testing!
        Next cell
    Next p

    rg.ClearContents
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Print job finished.", vbInformation, TITLE

End Sub
```

**My Logic for 3 Copies (`APPLY_TOTAL_LOGIC = TRUE`)**

```
1/12
2/12
3/12
4/12
5/12
6/12
7/12
8/12
9/12
10/12
11/12
12/12
```

**Your Logic For 3 Copies (`APPLY_TOTAL_LOGIC = FALSE`)**

```
1/3
2/3
3/3
4/3
5/3
6/3
7/3
8/3
9/3
10/3
11/3
12/3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done with a loop and a variable for each of the 4 cells you want to have printed.
After each iteration you have the variable value increase with four.

E.g. declare your variable

```
dim cell_m27 as integer
```

Before your loop you set value to one

```
cell_m27 = 1
```

In your loop you increase with one each time:

```
cell_m27 = cell_m27 + 4
```

And replicate for the other three variables, but start them with 2, 3 and 4.
Then they will increase with 4 for each loop until you reach your xCount and the loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub IncrementPrint()

    Dim xCount As Variant, xScreen As Boolean, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range, bOK As Boolean, msg as string
    
    msg = "Please enter the number of copies you want to print:"
    Set rng = Range("C27,M27,C58,M58")
    rng.ClearContents
    rng.NumberFormat = "@"
    
LInput:

    xCount = Application.InputBox(msg)
    If TypeName(xCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub

    bOK = False
    If IsNumeric(xCount) Then
        bOK = xCount > 0
    End If
    
    If bOK Then
        
        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        i = 0
        Do While i <= xCount
            For Each c In rng.Cells
                i = i + 1
                If i <= xCount Then
                    c.Value = i & "/" & xCount
                End If
            Next
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut
            rng.ClearContents
        Loop        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen

    Else
        MsgBox xCount & " not numeric,please enter again", vbInformation
        GoTo LInput
    End If
End Sub
```